# Connecting an address (UITextView) to the Apple Maps

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, apple-maps

I am trying to implement some feature:

I want a UITextView, which happens to be an address of some place, lead the user to the Apple Maps when tapping on this UITextView and show the location of the address in a UITextView. Any ideas on how I can do it?

What I have tried doing so far:

```swift
import MapKit

@IBOutlet weak var firstAddressTapped: UITextView!

func viewDidLoad() {
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "The address of my place")
  attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=The+address+of+my+place", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))
     firstAddressTapped.attributedText = attributedString
 }

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
     return false
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great simple tutorial by Alexander Adelmaer on Medium helped me solve my problem! Enjoy.

https://medium.com/app-makers/how-to-add-a-tap-gesture-to-uilabel-in-xcode-swift-7ada58f1664

What I've done wrong:

Tried to implement the feature in a wrong file when I was supposed to add it to View Controller.

How I solved:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 self.setupLabelTap()
   }
}

 @objc func labelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
                if let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?address=My+Address") {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
        print("The label is tapped!")
    }


func setupLabelTap() {

        let labelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelTapped(_:)))
        self.myView.labelAddress.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.myView.labelAddress.addGestureRecognizer(labelTap)
    }
```

Moreover, you definitely don't need MapKIT to use UITapRecognizer to open the Apple Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the address like that;

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
   // check if user touched the link.
   if range == NSRange(location: 19, length: 55) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?address=The+address+of+my+place")!)
   }
   return false
}
```

Comment: where do I pass that in a code snippet presented above?

Comment: You can put inside the function of delegate. I added the whole code.